# How can I convert string formatted UTC dates without offset to local time in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I am getting a string formatted date with UTC timezone. I need to convert this date time in user's current time zone using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) or [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

I am getting this:

```
9:43pm 16/10/2015 //this is UTC time, I am getting this via an ajax call
```

I need to convert it to this:

```
12:00pm 16/10/2015 //whatever time by that location
```

Comment: do you can use moment.js?

Comment: is that the actual format sent? Do you control the api source?

Comment: @charlietfl yes this is the actual time format sent from php

Comment: @CarloG. I do not have knowledge of moment.js, it will be good if I can get this by jquery or javascript

Comment: will need to parse that string to create a `Date` object or change format sent to avoid parsing and just pass to `new Date()`

Comment: What about this: if you send milliseconds since the epoch from your php and format on client site, it will always be in the proper TZ?

Comment: @AnshulMishra I revised my answer a few times to really try and get your exact format conversion. Could you check it out and let me know if helpful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can pick that format apart, or get a standard format JavaScript can parse - you can convert it to a `Date` object. I'm not seeing an offset on that date which is problematic when JavaScript tries to parse it. Assuming that is all you have, we can force a UTC date with the following...

```
// ------- new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second))
var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2015, 9, 16, 21, 43, 0));

console.log(date) // Fri Oct 16 2015 15:43:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time (Mexico))
```

- note that `month` in `Date.UTC` is zero based e.g. October would be `9`

`new Date(value)` would do this for us automatically if the format is correct - where `value` is the actual date value you receive - but that format will not parse as is. If there is no way around that format, you can manipulate it to work in the above example. Here is an **untested** algorithm for your example...

```
var formatted = '9:43pm 16/10/2015'

function createDateUTC(formatted) {

    var hourOffset =  formatted.split(' ')[0].split(':')[1].match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g)[0] === 'pm' ? 12 : 0

    var year = parseInt(formatted.split('/').pop());
    var month = parseInt(formatted.split('/')[1]) - 1;
    var day = parseInt(formatted.split('/')[0].split(' ').pop());
    var hour = hourOffset + parseInt(formatted.split(' ')[0].split(':')[0]);
    var minute = parseInt(formatted.split(' ')[0].split(':')[1]);

    return new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, 0));
}

var myDate = createDateUTC(formatted);
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/enm1frz8/) - working demo

Check out the [UTC()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_utc.asp) and [Date Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) docs for more info

---

Additionally, to get the exact format you want, we can introduce some more functions which will give us the `12:00pm 16/10/2015` format

```
function formatAMPM(date) {
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
    hours = hours % 12;
    hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
    var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + '' + ampm;
    return strTime;
}

function formatMMDDYYYY(inputFormat) {
    function pad(s) { return (s < 10) ? '0' + s : s; }
    var d = new Date(inputFormat);
    return [pad(d.getDate()), pad(d.getMonth()+1), d.getFullYear()].join('/');
}

console.log(formatAMPM(myDate) + ' ' + formatMMDDYYYY(myDate));
// Mountain Daylight Time => -- 3:43pm 16/10/2015
```

[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/4kkxrdau/) - formatted example

I'd reccoment looking into [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) if you plan to do heavy date formatting and manipulation.

---

Overall - the best solution to this would be to return an acceptable format from the server, resolve it to local time natively e.g. `new Date()`, and use a robust formatting library as opposed to rolling your own to display it how you wish.

Comment: thanks for the solution, I am bit confuse on one thing. Actually I am getting date time in south Australia Time Zone and I need to convert this in the user's current location's Time Zone. Here I did not understand that where we are converting the Time Zone in user's time zone.

Comment: Okay I think I was not get the code, now I have understand where it is converting to my Time Zone, but where we are passing that, the given date time is in South Australia Time Zone. For example If I will convert South Australia Time (11:30 17/10/2015) to UTC then it will return different time and if I will convert Asia/Kolkata Time (11:30 17/10/2015) to UTC then it will return different time. So I think we also need to pass the time zone of given time some where.

Comment: those both seem to be the same time. Doesn't matter the name of it, my example says Mexico but I am in USA - but the time is correct. It's driven by the system clock of the OS. I guess I'm really confused with your response - why exactly is this not working for you?

Comment: that was not exactly what I want, I think I did not ask question properly :( , but no issue your code helps me a lot, I have used a part of your code for my solution and I have understand that how it works and how to play with time in javascript. So thanks a lot for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You should process that string a little bit to extract year, month, day, hour and minute.

Then you can create a local date with that UTC date using this:

```
var time = new Date ( Date.UTC('year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute') );
```

In my case, '9:43pm 16/10/2015' returns: 'Mon Nov 16 2015 07:43:00 GMT-0200 (Hora de verano de Argentina)'.

Comment: how is this any different from the answer I posted earlier?

Comment: I didn't saw your answer, I was checking the results of this and it took more than the difference of time between our answers. Your answer has a flaw though, you should check if hour is pm or am to add 12 or not. Good luck!

Comment: I tried to accommodate for the hour offset thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Actually my issue is, I am getting date time of south Australia time zone, and I need to convert this in user's time zone, how can we achieve this.

Comment: This code executes on the browser, it should use the time zone of the users clock!